# Vector Spaces and proving equation involving dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be a nonzero subspace of $V$ , and suppose $T$ is a one-to-one
linear mapping of $V$ into $W$. Prove that $\dim T(H) = \dim H$. If $T$ happens to be a one-to-one mapping of $V$ onto $W$, then show that $\dim V = \dim W$.

Comment: Yes indeed; no pressure to accept an answer if none really help...no one expects any asker to ALWAYS accept an answer! I think you're even at a point where you can upvote answers! (rep wise).

Answer (score 2):

First, observe that the second point follows immediately from the first one. Since you can take $H=V$ and you have $T(V)=W$.

For the first point, we have first to observe that a one-to-one linear mapping sends a linearly independent set of vectors to a linearly independent set of vectors.

So assume $(v_j)$ is linearly independent. Now if $\sum x_jT(v_j)=0$, we can rewrite this linear compination as $T(\sum x_jv_j)=0$. So by injectivity of $T$, it follows that $\sum x_jv_j=0$. Now since the $v_j's$ are linearly independent, this forces $x_j=0$ for all $j$.
So $(T(v_j))$ is a linearly independent set.

Now if $(v_j)$ spans $H$, every $h\in H$ can be written $h=\sum x_jv_j$, so $T(h)=\sum x_j T(v_j)$. Hence $(T(v_j))$ spans $T(H)$.

Now, it is clear that a basis of $H$ is sent by $T$ to a basis of $T(H)$. So their dimensions are equal.